# How should I append both an anchor and image tag to a container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code but I now need to have the image tag wrapped in an anchor tag with attributes. I would like to do this without using jQuery's `.html()` method.

**Current JavaScript:**

```
$('<img/>', {
    id: 'myID',
    src: 'myURL',
    class: 'myClass'
}).appendTo('#myContainer');
```

Comment: Append the image to the anchor, then append anchor to the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a neat little solution:

```
$('<img>', {
    id: 'myID',
    src: 'myURL',
    class: 'myClass'
}).appendTo($('<a>', {           /* append the `img` to a new anchor */
    href: 'http://link.com/to/whatever',
    moreattributes: 'attributevalues'
}).appendTo('#myContainer'));    /* and put the anchor inside `#myContainer` */
```

Comment: It would be awesome if the downvoter could contribute why they think this answer isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('<img/>', {
id: 'myID',
src: 'myURL',
class: 'myClass'
}).wrap('<a href="#" />').parent().appendTo('#myContainer');
```

Comment: Could you explain what this does?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wrap use [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$('<img/>', {
    id: 'myID',
    src: 'myURL',
    class: 'myClass'
}).wrap('<a href="#" class="your_class" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)** to wrap your image inside anchor then use **[parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)** to append both of your image and anchor inside the container:

```
$('<img/>', {
    id: 'myID',
    src: 'myURL',
    class: 'myClass'
}).wrap('<a href="#"></a>').parent().appendTo('#myContainer');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2UhqQ/)**